# Using a simple for loop to match state name with corresponding state number

Tags: r

[image]

I web **scraped** 50 states from a website and added them to my data set under the name "state_name", I need to correspond all the state values 1 with Alabama all state values 2 with Alaska, etc...

Comment: FYI it’s __scraped__ not scrapped

Answer (score 0):

```
df$state_value = as.factor(df$state_name)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
df$state_value <- as.integer(factor(df$state_name))
```

or

```
df$state_value <- match(df$state_name,unique(df$state_name))
```